# Python/Pandas - Time Series Forecasting: Building a temporal data frame from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Im working on a Time series forecasting model, and looking for some advice on generating the input dataframe for the model. I have two datasets 1. Sales by date and 2. Orders by date and i would like to combine them as shown below:

DF1: Sales

| Date | Sales | store_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-23 | 1000 | TX | ABC1 |
| 2021-08-24 | 500 | NY | ABC2 |
| .......... | ... | -------- | -------------- |

DF2: Orders

| Date | Orders | store_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-24 | 2000 | TX | ABC1 |
| 2021-08-25 | 300 | NY | ABC2 |
| .......... | ... | -------- | -------------- |

Input date frame for Model (combine sales by date and capture the orders received for trailing n days):

| Date | Sales | store_id | product_id | n-1 Orders | n-2 Orders | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-23 | 1000 | TX | ABC1 | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-08-24 | 500 | NY | ABC2 | ... | ... | ... |
| .......... | ... | -------- | -------------- | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: What is in columns `n-1 Orders`, `n-2 Orders` from input data sample?

Comment: updated the question. Basically they capture the orders received in the trailing n days

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) in dict comprehension, create DataFrame by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

s = df2.set_index('Date')['Orders']

f = lambda x: f'n{x} Orders'
df = (pd.concat({x: s.shift(x, freq='d') for x in range(-1, -3, -1)}, axis=1)
        .rename(columns=f))
print (df)
            n-1 Orders  n-2 Orders
Date                              
2021-08-22         NaN      2000.0
2021-08-23      2000.0       300.0
2021-08-24       300.0         NaN
```

And then use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df1.join(df, on='Date')
print (df)
        Date  Orders  n-1 Orders  n-2 Orders
0 2021-08-23    1000      2000.0       300.0
1 2021-08-24     500       300.0         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael... Appreciate it... if my dataframes had additional columns such as store_id and product_id, how would i go about it? I would have to group them together to get the series based on each combination?  updating my question on these lines...

Comment: @redwolf_cr7 - Do you think in `df1` ? How should be processes another columns?

Comment: @redwolf_cr7 - Can you add some data there? Do you need merge by this new columns? Or something else?

Comment: Sure... i will update the df's with sample data... yes ideally i would have merge by these new columns to maintain the data integrity...

Comment: @redwolf_cr7 - OK, please add there some sample data and expected ouput, replace `---` and `.` please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236339/discussion-between-redwolf-cr7-and-jezrael).